# Why doesn't Label receive string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have two views and two classes. On the first view, controlled by the first class I have a textfield and a button. On the second view controlled by the second class I have two labels. I tried to make one label receive the value I put on the text field, and the other label this value divided by 100. But on both cases I get 0.00, I don't know why!

firstclass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NotasViewController : UIViewController{

}

-(IBAction)calcular:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clicarFora:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)recuarTeclado:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inserirTF;


@end
```

fisrtclass.m

```
#import "NotasViewController.h"
#import "resultadoViewController.h"

@interface NotasViewController ()

@end

@implementation NotasViewController
@synthesize inserirTF;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)calcular:(id)sender{

    float valor = [inserirTF.text floatValue];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    resultadoViewController *second = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"resultado"];
    second.resultadoFloatValor = valor;
    NSLog(@"%.2f", second.resultadoFloatValor);
}

-(IBAction)recuarTeclado:(id)sender{

    [sender resignFirstResponder];

}

-(IBAction)clicarFora:(id)sender{

    [inserirTF resignFirstResponder];

}

@end
```

secondclass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface resultadoViewController : UIViewController{

    float resultadoFloatValor;

}

@property float resultadoFloatValor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelValor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelQtd100;

@end
```

secondclass.m

```
#import "resultadoViewController.h"

@interface resultadoViewController ()

@end

@implementation resultadoViewController
@synthesize resultadoFloatValor, resultadoLabelValor, resultadoLabelQtd100;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *resultadoStringValor = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", resultadoFloatValor];
    NSLog(@"%.2f", resultadoFloatValor);
    NSLog(@"%@", resultadoStringValor);
    resultadoLabelValor.text = resultadoStringValor;

    int resultadoIntResto100 = resultadoFloatValor/100;

    if (resultadoIntResto100 > 0) {

        NSString *resultadoStringQtd100 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", resultadoIntResto100];
        resultadoLabelQtd100.text = resultadoStringQtd100;

    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

You'll see 3 NSLogs on my code. For testing, I put 54 on my textfield. The Output was like this:

```
2013-01-12 21:15:27.020 Divisorreal[21843:c07] 54.00
2013-01-12 21:15:27.023 Divisorreal[21843:c07] 0.00
2013-01-12 21:15:27.023 Divisorreal[21843:c07] 0.00
```

PS: All my Outlets are correctly connected to the UILabels.

Comment: Do you actually **present** the second class?

Comment: It really helps if you add some text in the `NSLog` methods so you can tell one from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best guess:

It looks like you are setting `resultadoFloatValor` after `viewDidLoad` is called.

Implement `prepareForSegue:` and set the value there.

Comment: Wait, how do you know that? He doesn't even show the code where he presents the second view controller, I don't see him reintializing resultadoFloatValor in viewDidLoad

Comment: It is a best guess based on the `NSLog` statements. If I remember correctly `viewDidLoad` is called early in segues. But that can easily be verified in the debugger with a couple of breakpoints. Not reintializing resultadoFloatValor, just that it has not been set yet.

Comment: Ah ok, I know almost nothing about storyboards, and I choose to keep it that way, those things look ugly!

Comment: @Rohan Well, they do cut down on the number of nib files, Plusses and minuses, I use both currently. iOS6 has helped somewhat but not as much as I would have hoped. The do add a bunch of code with `prepareForSegue` calls.

Comment: When I try to use them, they are just too hard and trivial for me, plus I want to make it iOS 5 compatible. So in my opinion, its a bit ehh

Comment: @Zaph "But that can easily be verified in the debugger with a couple of breakpoints." I don't know how, I've never used breakpoints... I'll try implementing prepareForSegue and set value there like you said.

Comment: Storyboards are iOS5 and above. Probably work better for iPhone as opposed to iPad. Just my experience so far.

Comment: viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear could probably work just the same.

Comment: @cdo To late,this is the caller setting a value.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the UITextView's delegate to send those actions to your controller.

Try putting a breakpoint in

```
-(IBAction)calcular:(id)sender
```

method to ensure its actually being called

Comment: That does not seem to be an issue here.

Comment: It's beeing called, it's connected to the only button in the screen, and then I press the button...